# What type to use for a class based React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a utility function that accepts a class based React component as a parameter. What should I type this as?

```
function doSomething(id: string, component: ???) {}
```

Comment: why don't you just import your component and use it as the type of the Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a functional component, you can try typing it as a `FunctionComponent` on your function's parameter.

```
function doSomething(id: string, component: FunctionComponent) {
  // do the rest
}
```

If it is a component class, you can try `ComponentClass` instead.

```
function doSomething(id: string, component: ComponentClass) {
  // do the rest
}
```

Comment: or maybe
`function doSomething(id: string, component: React.Component<T>) {
  // do the rest
}
`
assuming you imported React like : `import React from "react";`

Comment: I recommend using `ComponentType` instead. That way it can be either a class or function component.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(id: string, component: ReactNode) {}
```

It's the most suitable type